# How to optimize number recognition with Google Vision API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, ocr

I am experiencing strange behavior, when using this Vision ML API.

I am capturing images from a live stream and I have tens of thousands of key frames cropped for detection of a single digit against a clear background. However, the performance of the Google ML Vision API is very unreliable for such a simple task. I am wondering why that might be and what can I do about it?

I have some hypothesis:

- The language detection fails and leads to empty response, which I tend to get often (I have double checked that the empty response is not caused by authentication problems).
- The background some how makes the task hard.
- The numbers are too small; they are 35x35 images and the character lines are clear of width approximately 4 pixels.
- The live stream causes some artifacts, which are invisible to the eye, but very disturbing for the OCR.
- Google doesn't want us to use Vision API for these kinds of problem, and we should instead use pre-trained MNIST to recognize numbers.

I have used both, detect-text and detect-document; the latter is a bit more accurate.

Comment: I tried that also, but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

I came up with one solution, which seems to be working quite well.

I added text around the numbers (in order to give context) and then remove the text around with regexp and pick the numbers. It seems that the API is not for character recognition, but also likes to have some context words around the numbers to increase confidence. This solution works quite well for my use case and probably to many others also, since adding context text for the numbers is quite trivial thing to do ("My shoe number is: X"). Adding text to images should be trivial task to be done with ImageMagick.